# WPF Binding RelativeSource issue

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm using FindAncestor and AncestorLevel=3 to reach to the top level tag which should have the viewModel relay command, but it doesnt work. Any suggestions if I am doing it wrong or a way to debug this scenario?

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" Cursor="Hand"
                                           Foreground="Blue" TextDecorations="Underline">
                                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
                                            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding NameClickCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Grid, AncestorLevel=3}}" 
                                                                MustToggleIsEnabled="True" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
                                        </i:EventTrigger>
                                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </DataTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Comment: How about some specific code, so we don't have to use our glass balls?

Comment: Just a hunch after looking at your xaml quickly. It seems like you're binding the Command to a property called `NameClickCommand` on a `Grid`. `Grid` doesn't have this property, so try to change it to `Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.NameClickCommand...` if the NameClickCommand is in the DataContext of the Grid

Comment: @Meleak your answer worked. can you post it as an answer so that i accept it?

Comment: Sure thing, I'll change it to an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you're binding the Command to a property called NameClickCommand on a Grid. Grid doesn't have this property, so try to change it to

```
Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.NameClickCommand...
```

if the NameClickCommand is in the DataContext of the Grid

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the 3rd `Grid` up the hierarchy -- is that what you want?

Note that `Grid` does not include `DataGrid`.

Comment: Yes I'm looking only top parent of the xaml file which is a Grid and is at 3rd level from it. Is there a shortcut to refer to the root? or refer relative source by name of the component?

Comment: If I add a button at the same level of this Datagrid and set its command to NameClickCommand it works.

Comment: @11000011 `<Grid x:Name="rootGrid">` … `{Binding DataContext.NameClickCommand, ElementName=rootGrid}`